# Jquery DOM Manipulation - changing span

Tags: jquery, html

I have following HTML:

```
<div id="open_19" class="smile">
      <span><img src="http://localhost:3000/frontent_images/smiley.png"> </span>
      <span id="sum_19" class="value">12</span>
 </div>
```

When the user click on that id, the first span should change its src to another image (smiley_light.png).
I am having problems getting to that span to change its value.

If I use:

```
jQuery('.smile span img').mouseover(function(){
//jQuery(this).attr('src','/frontent_images/smiley_light.png');
```

});

It works, but I need direct control over it, since programatically I need ability to change that span.

I have tried the following, and it only adds another span instead of overwritting the existing one:

```
$("#open_" + mainid[1]).next("span").attr('src','/frontent_images/smiley_light.png');
```

Ideas?

Comment: You try to set the src attribute of a span ? What you want to achieve isn't clear. Maybe you should write the desired result ?

Comment: Use CSS for the span tag ([`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-image)) and change CSS styling on `mouseover`.

Comment: The click is on the span#sum_19, or on the div#open-19?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the click you're capturing is on the div you could do this:

```
$("#open_19").click(function(){
  $("img", this).attr("src", "/frontent_images/smiley_light.png");
});
```

This way you're only capturing the img elements inside the element that triggered the click event.

By the way, with this line:

```
$("#open_" + mainid[1]).next("span").attr('src','/frontent_images/smiley_light.png');
```

You're trying to select an span element that is in the same level as your div. In your html you don't have that. Also, a span element doesn't have a src attribute.

[Here's a JSFiddle of that code](http://jsfiddle.net/jVAme/).

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('.smile span img').mouseover(function(el){
   jQuery(el).attr('src','/frontent_images/smiley_light.png');
});
```

Not sure if this works, but try to pass the element to the function and use it later instead of "this"

Answer (score 0):

what you are doing will create a new span sibling to your clicked div . . . . . try changing next() to children() and use the pseudo selector 'span:first'

```
        $("#open_" + mainid[1]).children("span:first").attr('src','/frontent_images/smiley_light.png');
```